Quantile fastcforest in R
In the partykit implementation of cforest is possible to get quantile prediction as follows.
library(partykit)
library(moreparty)

## basic example: conditional inference forest for cars data
cf <- partykit::cforest(dist ~ speed, data = cars)

## prediction of fitted mean and visualization
nd <- data.frame(speed = 4:25)
nd$mean  <- predict(cf, newdata = nd, type = "response")
plot(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
lines(mean ~ speed, data = nd)

## predict quantiles (aka quantile regression forest)

myquantile <- function(y, w) quantile(rep(y, w), probs = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9))
p <- predict(cf, newdata = nd, type = "response", FUN = myquantile)
colnames(p) <- c("lower", "median", "upper")
nd <- cbind(nd, p)

fcf = fastcforest(dist ~ speed, data = cars, parallel=FALSE)

How can I achieve the same result with fastcforestin the library moreparty?
